# Continuous AJAX requests - effect on web app?

Tags: ajax, performance

I have a web app idea which will require AJAX requests to function. Its crucial that AJAX requests are running as long as the user is on the site.

My question is, if the user left the site up (my ajax requests will be running) for say 4/5 hours, will these AJAX requests still run, my concerns are screen dimming, screensavers, computer sleep states. Will all or none of these affect the performance of my web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's very client dependent.  For example, mobile devices may stop processing JS when going into a sleep state (e.g., to save battery life).  However, on an image rotator application I wrote some time ago, which sent regular requests to the server to retrieve images (there was good reason not to cache them, I swear), accessed primarily by non-mobile clients, I observed that requests continued for hours, even days.  While I can't know if the client machine ever entered a sleep state, I'm pretty confident it did.

Long story short - I think you can't be sure, but for some target audiences, you can be reasonably sure.  I would recommend investigating your audience.

Answer (score 0):

If in your site users require to login simple keep a session time out option to lets say 15 mins. That means after 15 mins of idle time the session will be destroyed and the ajax requests automatically truncated.

If you do not have login this becomes difficult but still can be achieved via ip tracking or similar mechanisms but these will never be as full proof as the first one.

Comment: This is language dependent, but session timeout is usually not enforced on a running script, it's checked at session start. so this might not work...

Comment: I am not asking to enforce session time out on a running script . It's similar to your mobile going into sleep mode. You detect if your mobile has entered into sleep mode . if yes you suspend it , right ? Similarly you can keep track of the idle time of the user and depending on that you can stop executing the ajax calls . Let me know if that makes any sense at all or not :( ?

Answer (score 0):

I must agree with Sean in that it it's very client side orientated. If the client stays active, be it through human interaction our not, then the AJAX should keep going.